# 12.10 Unity Counter Badges don't appear

Tags: unity, launcher, 12.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 last night, and none of my programs are displaying the little number badges for unread messages anymore. Affected programs include Thunderbird and Empathy.

I'm assuming this is a config issue or something. The problem is that I don't even know what these things are called, so Googling is showing me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new Thunderbird update fixed it for that program. Supposedly Empathy is supposed to work already, but it doesn't.

I guess this was just a bug due to some new messaging infrastructure.

It seems related to this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259

I'm still not sure what to call the little unread indicator, though.